# Updating Table depending on Duplicate record in database

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that will pull all the distinct records from a table full of duplicates.  My plan is to use this information to update a field in my database telling me that there is a duplicate of a particular record.

Here is an example showing what I want to accomplish

```
Table 1                     Table 2

ID     DuplicateId          ID      MD5 (Pretend these are correct)
1      Null                 1       25622
2      Null                 2       25622
3      Null                 3       86548
4      Null                 4       86548
```

The end result of the query should give me this

```
Table 1

ID     DuplicateId
1      
2      1
3      
4      3
```

This is a pretty simple example but it is the best I can come up with to explain my situation.   The end goal is pretty much a child/parent relationship if you want to think of it that way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if Table2 has another duplicated for `MD5=25622`?.

Comment: look up the HAVING COUNT(*) clause, also LAG functions

Comment: @Lamak, if there is another duplicate for 25622 then it will also get a value of 1 in Table 1.  I only need the first record each time stored in my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want with this query:

```
select t2a.id, (case when t2a.id <> min(t2b.id) then min(t2b.id) end) as DuplicateId
from Table2 t2a left outer join
     Table2 t2b
     on t2a.MD5 = t2b.MD5
group by t2a.id;
```

A more efficient way to implement it is:

```
select id, (case when id <> minid then minid end) as DuplicateId
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by MD5) as minid
      from Table2 t
     ) t
```

If you actually need this in another table, you can use `select into` or `insert`.

Comment: In your second query, you are comparing `id` with `MD5`, that isn't going to work

Comment: @Lamak,  Thank you Gordon and Lamak for the post and corrections.  The second solution you provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to calculate the row number of each similar MD5. Then get the ID of the first occurance of the MD5s and update Table 1.

```
;WITH ResultCTE AS
(
    SELECT    ID,
              MD5,
              ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MD5 ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM      Table2
)
UPDATE Table1
SET    DuplicateID = CASE 
                         WHEN T1.ID = T2.ID 
                         THEN NULL ELSE T2.ID 
                     END
FROM   Table1 T1
       JOIN Table2 T3
           ON T1.ID = T3.ID
       JOIN (
                SELECT ID, 
                       MD5 
                FROM   ResultCTE 
                WHERE  RowNum = 1
            ) T2
           ON T1.MD5 = T2.MD5
```

If Table1 doesn't have any values initially then:

```
;WITH ResultCTE AS
(
    SELECT    ID,
              MD5,
              ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MD5 ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM      Table2
)
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT    T1.ID,
          CASE 
              WHEN T1.ID = T2.ID 
              THEN NULL ELSE T2.ID 
          END AS DuplicateID 
FROM   Table2 T1
       JOIN (
                SELECT ID,
                       MD5 
                FROM   ResultCTE  
                WHERE  RowNum = 1
            ) T2
            ON T1.MD5 = T2.MD5
```

Comment: The issue I am seeing here is that Table 1 does not have the MD5 stored,  it is only in Table 2 as I show above.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Does Table 1 has values initially?